# Grails hasMany enum with a custom hibernate UserType

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have an enum with a hibernate custom UserType:

```
enum Program { ABC(1000), XYZ(1001); final long code; ... }

class ProgramUserType implements org.hibernate.usertype.UserType { ... }
```

The ProgramUserType stores the code (1000, 1001, etc) for the enum and gets the enum instance back via the code when read from the database.

This is in use successfully on a relationship in a domain class:

```
class MyDomainOne {
    Program program
    ...
    static mapping = {
        ...
        program column: 'PROGRAM_ID', type: ProgramUserType
        ...
    }
}
```

So, all of the above works fine.

But I want to use the enum in a hasMany relationship:

```
class MyDomainTwo {
    ...
    static hasMany = [
        programs: Program
    ]
    ...
    static mapping = {
        ...
        programs joinTable: [name: 'BLAH_DOM_TWO_PROGS', key: 'DOM_TWO_ID', column: 'PROGRAM_ID']
        ...
    }
}
```

My issue is that always produces a column with a "varchar2(255 char)" type:

```
BLAH_DOM_TWO_PROGS (DOM_TWO_ID number(19,0) not null, PROGRAM_ID varchar2(255 char));
```

I've tried various things to no avail:

```
programs joinTable: [name: 'BLAH_DOM_TWO_PROGS', key: 'DOM_TWO_ID', column: 'PROGRAM_ID', type: ProgramUserType]

programs joinTable: [name: 'BLAH_DOM_TWO_PROGS', key: 'DOM_TWO_ID', column: 'PROGRAM_ID', type: ProgramUserType, sqlType: 'NUMBER(10,0)']

programs type: ProgramUserType, joinTable: [...]
```

etc.

What is the proper syntax to use a custom user type in a join table mapping?

(I'm using grails 2.3.7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you do this complex but in order to write a code(Integer, Long, String...) into a column of database from an enum, you can implement simply like this:

```
enum Program {
    ABC(0, "ABC"),
    XYZ(1, "XYZ"),

    final String value
    final Integer id

    Program(Integer value, String selectValue) {
        this.id = value
        this.value = selectValue
    }

    //https://github.com/tudor-malene/Easygrid/issues/22
    //shows value in select drop down
    String toString() { value }

    //stores value in database
    Integer getId() { id }

    //returns Enum constant associated with value
    String getKey(){ name() }
}
```

The importance line of code is `Integer getId() { id }`
You can change id property to whatever type you want.
Hope it help

some reference links [GRAILS-3633](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3633) or [in another discussion](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Question-about-the-use-of-enum-types-in-Grails-td3220149.html)

Comment: I'm trying this out and it will be the answer I select if my tests pass.  Adding "long getId()" to the enum causes the generated ddl to be of type number(19,0).  I'm curious if you can point me to any grails docs showing that adding a getId() method to an enum results in this magic (i.e. not needing a custom UserType)... how does it resolve the id when reading from the database?

Comment: This was my initial thinking to make sure the enum itself provides the value similar to implementation of `toString()`, when used in association but I am not aware if `getId()` will do the trick. Eager to find out as well.

Comment: I have no idea how I've missed that you can add getId to enums in grails for years.  Thank you.  I will never write a custom UserType again.  And this worked for producing the correct join table defintion that I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: It comes to me when I want to find a solution to store enum as Integer in database but still show some String in select tag which is very convenience. I will update some links to my answer.

Comment: https://grails.org/1.1+Release+Notes 1.1?! now i feel even more dumb :)  but i've yet to find it mentioned in grails docs.

Answer (score 1):

`type` cannot be specified for the inverse column in joinTable. It looks like one should be able to mention any other column config from [this line](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/cfg/HibernateMappingBuilder.groovy#L510) but it does not work. You can raise a JIRA issue as enhancement/bug/feature request and/or drop the idea of using `joinTable` but create an actual domain class to handle the XRef table. For example, in lines of something like:

```
class DomainProgram implements Serializable {

    MyDomainTwo myDomain
    Long programId

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['myDomain', 'programId']
        table 'DOMAIN_PROGRAM'
        myDomain column: 'DOMAIN_ID'
        programId column: 'PROGRAM_ID'
    }
}
```

with

```
class MyDomainTwo {
    def getPrograms() {
        DomainProgram.findByMyDomain(this)*.programId.collect { 
            Program.getEnum it 
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
enum Program {
    ABC(1000), XYZ(1001)

    final long code

    private Program(long _code) {
        code = _code
    }

    long getValue() {
        code
    }

    static Program getEnum(long value) {
        values().find { it.code == value }
    }
}
```

There will be a little bit of boiler plate code involved like implementing `equals()` and `hasCode()` in `DomainProgram` but will create the columns as desired.

Comment: Given that [link that you referenced](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/cfg/HibernateMappingBuilder.groovy#L510) it does look like you should be able to specify any [ColumnConfig attributes](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/cfg/ColumnConfig.html) (which do not include 'type')... i went back an tried sqlType by itself and even enumType: 'ordinal' but neither had any impact on the generated ddl.  After seeing that I'm thinking it is a bug.